# Declaring an object within its class

Tags: c++, processing, openframeworks

I'm trying to port the [Bouncing Bubbles](http://processing.org/learning/topics/bouncybubbles.html) Processing example into C++ (with OpenFrameworks) and I've run into a bit of a hitch.  In the definition of the class:

```
class Ball {
  float x, y;
  float diameter;
  float vx = 0;
  float vy = 0;
  int id;
  Ball[] others;

...

void collide() {
  for (int i = id + 1; i < numBalls; i++) {
    float dx = others[i].x - x;
    float dy = others[i].y - y;
    float distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

...
```

It looks like the object, "others" is being declared within its own class.  I've tried adding  `Ball others(<arguments>);` into my C++ class but XCode flashes angrily at me and leaves a console message threatening to eat my future children so I must be doing something wrong.  I'm thinking that this might be a Java/Processing thing - but I am pretty new to C++ classes.

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing in C++ or am I just better off moving the collide function out of the class and into the testApp class with some modifications?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a pointer and not an array:

```
...
Ball *others;
...
```

You cannot declare an object of the same type in the class definition because that would mean you need an object of infinite size, one that contains itself.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up using Ball **others since I needed an array of objects.  The code is working fine now albeit, physics are not quite right but it's good enough for now!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want an array of objects that grows/shrinks as needed. In that case, you can use a vector of `Ball` pointers:

```
std::vector<Ball*> others;
```

Creating new `Ball` instances and inserting them in the array works like this:

```
others.push_back(new Ball);
```

However, unlike Java, C++ does not have a garbage collector. So make sure to delete the elements again. For example, in the destructor of your class:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < others.size(); ++i) {
    delete others[i];
}
```

Or, if you're using C++-11, the shorter version using a range-based for loop:

```
for (auto ball : others) {
    delete ball;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution. In Processing which is basically Java syntax, when you have an array like this of it's own class, it acts as a resizable array of "pointers" to other Ball objects or instances. You don't really have pointers in Java or Java syntax which can be confusing. You might also come across the ArrayList being used in the same way. Vectors of pointers to other objects in c++ is the best way to go.

Comment: I agree, especially in terms of garbage collection should I decide to add or remove more balls during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It is **impossible** to declare an object which is a field of its own class. Because if that happens, when you declare an object of that class, the initialization process is a recursive call. It is analogous to the Java code like this

```
class Test {
Test t = new Test();
}
```

The above code will cause java.lang.StackOverflowError